# What is the least number of concerts needed to be scheduled in order that each musician may listen, as part of the audience, to every other musician?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Six musicians gathered at a music festival. At each concert
> some musicians played in the concerts while the others listened, as part
> of the audience. What is the least number of concerts needed to be scheduled in order that each musician may listen, as part of the audience, to
> every other musician?

I have managed to find that $4$ concerts works if we let the players be $A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$, then $A,B,C$ playing first, $B,E,F$ second, $C,D,E$ thirdly and $A,D,F$ last is a working construction.

Now the issue I'm having is that I cannot prove that the cases with $3,2$ and $1$ concerts are not possible.

Well the first one is easy since no two players are able to hear each other out ever, but how can I argue for the cases $3$ and $2$?

Comment: Well, every possible division for the first concert has one group (audience or performers) with at least three members, call them $A,B,C$.  Then, in the next concert two of those (at least) must be in the same group.

Comment: This problem appears in Terence Tao's book _Solving Mathematical Problems: A Personal Perspective_

Comment: @MJD Enjoyed your blog post - I think I remember reading it before! About different numbers of musicians: you wrote "I have a method that I'll describe in a future article". Did you ever get around to the sequel?

Comment: No, and I also forgot what the method was! 

Comment: This appears to be sequence [A305233](https://oeis.org/A305233) in the OEIS.

Comment: The description of A305233 says “Minimal size of a set with n subsets such that no one contains another”. I don't understand how that is isomorphic to this problem.

Comment: @MJD See my answer for an explanation of how the OEIS page applies to the case of $n$ musicians.

Comment: As this is Math.SE, I say we define the audience to be every person in the room who can hear the concert.  Then, trivially, the case of 1 concert is proven.

Comment: Those four acts would be part of one concert, so the obvious answer is 1.

Comment: Anything about bipartite graphs in this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a total of $6\cdot5=30$ (listener, performer)-pairs.

If at a concert we have $n$ performers, then in that concert there are $(6-n)n$ such (listener, performer)-pairs. The maximum value of $(6-n)n$ is $9$, achieved when $n=3$.

As $30/9>3$ there is no way three concerts would suffice. Congratulations on finding a set of four concerts that works!

Answer (score 14):

Given a schedule with $n$ concerts, define $S_1,\dots,S_6$ to be subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $S_i$ is corresponds to the set of concerts that musician number $i$ played in. For example, if $n=6$, and the third musician played in concerts numbered $2,4,$ and $5$, then $S_3=\{2,4,5\}$.

If $S_i\subseteq S_j$, then every concert $i$ played in would have $j$ playing also, meaning $j$ would never sit in the audience for $i$. Since we need to avoid this, it must be the case that $S_i\not\subseteq S_j$ for all $i,j\in \{1,\dots,6\}$, $i\neq j$. This means that the list $S_1,\dots,S_6$ is an *anitchain* in the Boolean poset of $2^{\{1,\dots,n\}}$. (For any set, $S$, $2^S$ is the set of subsets of $S$).

[Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) says that the largest antichain in $2^{\{1,\dots,n\}}$ has a size of $\binom n{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }$. Therefore, in the case where $n=3$, the largest antichain has size $\binom 31=3$. Since no antichain of size $6$ exists, you cannot succeed with only three concerts. On the other hand, you showed that you can suceed with four concerts, so you have found the optimal solution. In fact, since $\binom 42=6$, there is no "slack", and you need to use the maximal antichain of the size-two subsets of $2^{\{1,2,3,4\}}$. Every valid schedule is therefore equivalent to yours, up to permutation of people and concerts.

An example of a schedule is below. Note if you read by columns, you see every pattern of $2$ X's and $2$ blanks exactly once.
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
 & M_1&M_2&M_3&M_4&M_5&M_6
\\\hline
C_1 & \times &\times &&\times &&
\\
C_2 &\times &&\times &&\times 
\\
C_3 & &\times &\times & &&\times
\\
C_4 &&&&\times&\times&\times 
\end{array}
$$

In general, if there are $n$ musicians, then in order to succeed with $k$ concerts, it is necessary that
$$
\binom{k}{\lfloor k/2\rfloor} \ge n
$$
Therefore, the optimal number of concerts is the smallest such $k$ for which the above is true. This corresponds to the following OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A305233. You can prove that
$$
\text{# concerts needed for $n$ musicians}=\log_2 n+\frac12\log_2 \log_2 n +O(1)
$$
as $n\to\infty$. You can prove this using the fact that $\binom k{k/2}\sim (\pi k/2)^{-1/2}2^k$ as $k\to\infty$.

The optimal schedule for $n$ musicians is as follows. With $k$ defined as above, assign each musician a distinct subset of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ whose cardinality is $\lfloor k/2\rfloor$. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, the $i^\text{th}$ musician will play in concert number $j$, for each $j$ in their assigned set.

Comment: +1 I did not know/recall Sperner's theorem. There was a (low quality) question yesterday, that would have benefitted from having it. I did suggest $\binom{2\ell}\ell$ construction in a comment, but can't find the question now. May be it was deleted?

Comment: An advantage of this approach is that you've shown three concerts would still be insufficient even if we only had four performers.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Indeed. More generally, if there are $n$ musicians, my approach implies the optimal number $k$ of concerts is the smallest number for which $\binom k{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}\ge n$, which implies $k=\log_2 n +\frac12\log_2\log_2 n +O(1)$.